# Keep url params even during session end redirect to login page

Tags: java, keycloak

I use SSO to login to my website. If I want to change my password I go to:

> http://localhost:8086/auth/realms/master/account/password?back_url=https://www.example.com/it/profile/&kc_locale=en

I include 2 params in the url. Most of the time this is working well but sometimes the session has ended and then I'm redirected to the SSO login page losing the params.

Is there any way to keep the param even during the redirect?

Comment: Can you store the params in a cookie or session variable? When the user hits the default page after authenticating, the cookie or session values can be retrieved and redirect the user from the controller.

Comment: Yes I already do this, I store the back_url in a sessionStorage but it seems that the redirect is happening in the backend and the javascript code never runs. TBH I don't know how to do this in keycloak.